# command to show list all users and date the logged in

Tags: command-line

Which command to shows list of all users and date the logged in a Linux system. I have tried last -a but its not showing the list of all users and date the logged.

Answer (score 1):

`who` is the command you want, see `man who`

```
$ who -uH
NAME     LINE         TIME             IDLE          PID COMMENT
walt     tty7         2019-08-01 23:39  old         3561 (:0)
```

If you want older logs, see `/var/log/auth.log*`. It has more data than just logins, so start with something like:

```
zgrep login /var/log/auth.log*
```

Comment: thanks @waltinator. $ who -uH only displays today's login. Am looking for command that would display login for the last one month.